# Unable to make flexbox item to get full height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm still learning Flexbox and right now I'm facing an issue with a flexbox item.

`header-left` is a flex container with two items, `logo and nav menu`. `Nav Menu` has 3 links. As I'm using `flexbox`, the `navigation` div takes its own height and not the height of the whole `header` container. And because of that the anchor links doesn't take the height of its grandparent's, that is 100% height.

How can I use flexbox and still have full height? This issue is affecting my hover dropdown menu.

Here's the snippet:

```css
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-left {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo{
    background-color: #2e3032;
    padding: 20px 28px;
}

.logo__image{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

.navigation{
    position: relative;
}

.navigation a{
    margin-left: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c7cacc;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-left">
     <a href="#" class="logo">
            <img class="logo__image" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/00/16/07/115783931601b5c.jpg" >
     </a>

    <div class="navigation">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#" id="by-topic">Products</a>
        <a href="#" id="by-author">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to this:

```
.header-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height:140px; <---Logo height plus padding
 }


.navigation{
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  background:cadetblue;
}
```

If you explicitly set the height of header-left you can then use height:100% on it's children to fill the full height.
You just need to recenter the nav links with flex after that.